# What is the significance of the constant spitting of Josey Wales?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-outlaw-josey-wales

In [*The Outlaw Josey Wales*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Outlaw_Josey_Wales), Josey Wales always spits something from his mouth.

It's a Western movie, the lead role should act decent. But this guy, Josey Wales, always spits like an old man.

What is the significance of his constant spitting?

Comment: Have you ever heard of chewing tobacco? I've never seen this film but it's a possible explanation that is common in Western films.

Comment: @Paulie_D Which makes for an insightful answer actually, since the heroes in Westerns before European Spaghetti Westerns and American Revisionist Westerns (of which *The Outlaw Josie Wayles* is a good example) came around *were indeed* supposed to be "decent" people. Looking beyond misunderstandings and taking them as opportunities for good and interesting answers can sometimes help to not see every question as falsely premised and bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a short answer, it's not *spitting* exactly.

Josey is indulging in chewing tobacco.

> [**Chewing tobacco**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chewing_tobacco) is a type of smokeless tobacco product consumed by placing a portion of the tobacco between the cheek and gum or upper lip teeth and chewing. Unlike dipping tobacco, it is not ground and must be manually crushed with the teeth to release flavour and nicotine. **Unwanted juices are then expectorated (spat)**

Generally, if one was polite, and indoors, there was a special receptacle where one could put the unwanted "juice". It was called a spittoon.

[image: picture of old West spitton on a floor]

You'd see them in many Westerns of old the pre-revisionist Western era although generally they probably wouldn't have been used onscreen unless it was for a specific point. Such as in [***Rio Bravo***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053221/) where a drunkard Deam Martin is taunted to fish for the price of a drink when a dollar is thrown into a spittoon.

---

Coming to your (as it's been indicated) more interesting point...

> It's a Western movie, the lead role should act like decent.

Yes, that was the case up to the mid-1950's, Westerns usually had well-defined, often one-note heroes in white hats and villains in black.

These Westerns were often churned out by the studios at a prodigious rate often one a week with little plot variation or action.

That started to change towards the end of that decade, movies in general became more gritty &/or realistic and the Western genre changed equally.

Heroes weren't one dimensional anymore; heroes sometimes had agendas or major character flaws; revenge (albeit for a good cause/reason) was sometimes a driving factor for a protagonist hero.

These heroes/protaginists were more interesting and [**The Revisionist Western, Modern Western or Anti-Western (Wikipedia)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revisionist_Western) sub-genre really got underway in the early 1960's (although there were earlier examples).

> Some post-WWII Western films began to question the ideals and style of the traditional Western. Elements include a darker, more cynical tone, with focus on the lawlessness of the time period, favoring realism over romanticism. Anti-heroes are still common, but with stronger roles for women and more-sympathetic portrayal of Native Americans and Mexicans. Regarding power and authority, these depictions favor critical views of big business, the American government, masculine figures (including the military and their policies), and a turn to greater historical authenticity.

*The Outlaw Josey Wales* is a good example of this genre.